# DBT pass a set variable to another set variable

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

How can I set a runtime variable in my SQL file that references other runtime variables or macros?

For example:

```
{% set var2= [mylist] %}
{% set var1=dbt_utils.star(from=table, except=var2) % }
```

My code fails to compile whenever I try to do this. Can I call a macro in the set context instead?